# Griffiths example 2.10 (conductor with a cavity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, conductors

The problem is related to a conductor with a cavity containing a charge $q$.

Griffiths in the example states that the field generated by the induced charge $-q$ on the inner surface cancels out in every point outside the inner surface.

Then it gives an explanation related to the uniqueness theorems of the potential.

Can someone explain to me how to apply these theorems to deduce Griffith's conclusion?

I added a photo about the problem.
The question is to find the field outside a uncharged sphere with a cavity containing a point charge $q$.

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what's up without getting too detailed with the math.

If you have an electric field inside the conductor, charge will move, it is not in a static state. It's assumed its a static state, so the field must be zero.

By Gauss' Law, net charge within a volume means non-zero flux through its boundary and vice versa. We only have no field (in the static case) if we have no net charge.

Consider the wall of the conductor forming the boundary of the cavity. Just inside the cavity there is a field. Just inside the conductor there is no field. The only way that can happen is if there is an accumulation of charge that exactly cancels out the amount of charge within the cavity otherwise there would be net flux and a non-zero field. We have a field contributed by the charge inside the cavity canceling out the field created by the charge accumulated on the interior wall.

There is field just inside the cavity and no field just inside the conductor. Using an infinitesimal, cylindrical Gaussian Surface one can demonstrate the charge is accumulated on the surface and find the surface charge density from the discontinuity of the field. Further, the field is normal to the surface.

Those electrons have to come from somewhere, so they've left gaps within the conductor. If there were no cavity, an accumulation of positive charge in the conductor would spread out to the surface of the conductor. Something similar  happens. There must be positive charged "gaps" and their fields interact with each other so that they end up on the surface of the conductor. This occurs for the same amount of charge regardless of the reason for its being there, induced, some how added to a neutral conductor, etc.

So the net charge on the conductor remains zero. Any surface containing the conductor (and its cavity) will then contain a net charge of what's inside the cavity,q. A net charge implies a non-zero field.

In Electro statics, Faraday's Law allows us to use $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ for some potential $V$ since the time derivative of the  magnetic field is zero and a zero curl of the electric field implies it is the gradient of some potential. Combined with Gauss's Law, this tells us that $-\nabla^2V=\rho/\epsilon_0. $ $\rho=0$ in regions where there is no charge, so the equation becomes, $\nabla^2V=0$, Laplace's Equation.

Now that we have a partial differential equation, theorems for existence and uniqueness apply. Given a linear equation like this, that typically only requires suitable boundary conditions. The super-position principle also comes into play.

$\vec{E}=0\iff -\nabla V=0$. This means the entire conductor has to be at the same potential. Call that $V(\delta B)=V_0$ where $\delta B$ represents the outer boundary of the conductor. This is one possible boundary condition. Since the value of the function is specified, this is a Dirichlet Boundary Conditon.  Knowledge of the actual field can serve is well. The charge density on the surface of a conductor is proportional to the field discontinuity at the surface, so specifying the surface charge can also work. The specification of the value of a derivative on the surface is a Neumann Boundary Condition.

Suppose $-\nabla^2(V_1)=-\nabla^2(V_2)=0$ Then $\nabla^2(V_2-V_1)=0=\nabla\cdot \nabla (V_2-V_1)$.

By Gauss' Law: $0=\int   \nabla (V_2-V_1) \cdot \hat{n} dA$ This applies to any Gaussian surface, so $\hat{n}$ is arbitary. The integral can only be zero for arbitray surfaces if the integrand is identically zero. It follows that $\nabla(V_2-V_1)\equiv 0$. So $V_2-V_1=c$ for some constant $c$. Thus $V$ is unique up to an additive constant. Since $-\nabla(V+c)=-\nabla(V)=\vec{E}$, the value of the constant doesn't matter and the field has been uniquely determined.

The field due to a point charge is known, just from Coulomb's Law. Gauss' Law tells us the field contribution by the surface charge of the inner wall needs to cancel out that charge's field. This tells us the surface charge, so gives us a Neumann Boundary Condition for  the field due to the inner wall's charges.  The field just outside the conductor has to reflect the net charge distribution of inside the associated Gaussian surface which net only contains the charge within the cavity. This gives us another Neumann Boundary condition. We have 3 fields that sum to a total field by the superposition principle. This field solves Laplace's equation and the boundary conditions at yields zero in the conductor.

Intuitively, a PDE tells you how the value of the function changes as you move through space. The boundary condition tells you the initial values. If you have a rule for how the value changes from the boundary to some other point, and you know the value at the boundary, then you know the value of the function at the new point.

Comment: Thank you for the accurate answer. Actually the thing that wasn't clear is why Griffiths say that it is sufficient that we sum the two fields,the one of the charge and the one produced from the inside cavity to obtain E=0 in all the space. Griffiths say that we can see this using the uniqueness theorems but I can't see how ...

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: Have you got any ideas?

Comment: By Gauss' Law a static charge distribution on a boundary contributes no field to a volume within that boundary, so only the charge effects the inside of the cavity. Now any surface just inside the conductor will contain the induced charge on the inner wall as well as the cavity's charge. This has to be zero since the total field is zero and  the outer wall's charge doesn't effect it.  To cancel the field, there must be a specific distribution of charge on the inner wall, but a specific charge distribution is a Neumann Condition which yields a unique solution to Laplace's Equation.

Comment: If we ignore the outer wall's charge, any Gaussian surface just outside of the conductor is going to have zero net charge, so the total field (of charge plus induced) will be zero in all space.

Comment: First statement you say: why is it? Don't we know only that the flux is 0( not E)

Comment: 0 flux implies 0 field. For a given charge and arbitrary Gaussian surface around it, the sign of the field is the sign of the charge. The cosine of the angle the field makes with the surface is always positive and infinitesimal area is always positive, so each infinitesimal contribution of flux for a given charge maintains the sign of that charge. 

For a given charge, we won't have a negative patch of flux here and a positive patch of flux there so that they cancel. The only way to add up contributions of the same sign to get zero is if all contributions are zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, i still don't understand why a static distribution on a boundary of a conductor necessarily implies the absence of the field related to the distribution inside.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you have a charge distribution on a surface, it doesn't produce a field in a  volume within, however, charge within that volume not part of the surface can produce a field. In other words, the charge on the inner wall doesn't effect the cavity, but the charge in the cavity does have a field. 

By Gauss' Law the flux integral within a charge distribution will always be zero if the volume enclosed does not have any charge. 

Coulomb's law implies the same thing for certain geometries: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem . As it turns out that can be generalized.